Concurrent transactions using Snowflake.Connector in FastAPI service
I am using a single snowflake.connector connection object inside a Singleton DB class.
When I receive multiple Rest API calls, there is highly likelyhood of Concurrent transactions happening on the data related to same table.
On a single connection, are concurrent transactions supported? By the way, I am using cursors to execute my inserts and updates and calling connection.commit()
Thanks for your help.
